# SQL Using sum command with "in" clause

Tags: sql

I have sql tables listed as picture below.

[image]

And my Query is :

```
       Select * from tblOrderDetails where OrderID in 
          (Select OrderID from tblOrders where CustomerID = 523456)
```

Which returns values from tblOrderDetails like

[image]

Query brings all sale details for selected customer as expceted. But I want to use SUM on rows which has same ProductID. Expected output should look like this :

[image]

Rows with same productID, quantity and price gets summed and also rows are merged. But it must be done within selected CustomerID.

I've tried SUM command with many different ways but can't get it to work. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use images to demonstrate things here unless they're absolutely necessary. They're harder to read, many proxy servers block them (mine, for instance - I see "tblOrderDetails like" and a large block of white screen, and "should look like this" and a block of white screen), and the content is impossible to copy/paste. It's also not searchable, and isn't nice to users with limited bandwidth. Put the text representation into your question and properly format it so that it's easily seen. Thanks.

Comment: Never a good idea to do `SELECT *`, only select the columns you need to bring back.  Without seeing your `SUM` attempts, I'm guessing this is at least partially caused you problems.

Comment: You need to read a basic introduction to SQL. You're not yet at the point where you are ready to ask questions.

Comment: @KenWhite I'll consider this on my next Questions. Thanks for info.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Yes, as you stated I didn't need for select * for the last picture, but only few columns.

Comment: @Dmitri I'm not going to be developer. Just trying to achieve few little things. Which brings the conclussion that I don't want to use my time on learning. Since I can learn it logically by the answers. Thanks to other users. Love the community here. Even I don't get any answer that would be ok for me. I appreciate everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you don't know about the GROUP BY clause.

Perhaps this is what you are trying to do?

```
Select CustomerID,ProductId,SUM(Quantity) Quantity,SUM(TotalPrice) TotalPrice from tblOrderDetails where OrderID in (Select OrderID from tblOrders where CustomerID = 523456)
GROUP BY CustomerID,ProductId
```

This groups everything by same customer then by same products, allowing the SUMs only on those merged subsets

Comment: You can also replace the unnecessary `IN` clause with a simple `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables  Very correct, this would actually be cleaner.  I just copied OP's query

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It worked. But I had to remove CustomerID from query to get it work.

Comment: @EkriirkE I have a little inquiry, Can we also get ProductName from tblProduct wtih your query ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to move to JOINs with tblProduct `FROM tblOrderDetails INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblProduct.ProductID=tblOrderDetails.ProductID`  Add ProductID to the SELECT and GROUP BY sections

Answer (score 1):

You'll be wanting to use SUM and GROUP BY to attain the results you're looking for.

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, SUM(TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice
FROM tblOrderDetails
WHERE OrderID IN
(
    SELECT OrderID
    FROM tblOrders
    WHERE CustomerID = 523456
)
GROUP BY ProductID
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean&tidy explanation.